# Problema com roteamento de rotas asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho a seguinte rota, onde recebo o id do representante:
http://localhost:18568/Representante/Index/1

Assim está funcionando, mais eu gostaria de mostra o nome do representante 
http://localhost:18568/nome-do-representante /Index/JsBlaBla

no meu MapRoute estou fazendo assim sem sucesso

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Representante",
              url: "nome-do-representante/Index/{chave}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Representante", action = "Index" },
              constraints: new { chave = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/_]{2,}$" }
            );



            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para funcionar exatamente isso: http://localhost:18568/nome-do-representante/Index/1234, teria que ser da forma abaixo, mas terá problemas.

As partes da rota:

{representante}  / {action}  / {chave}

jose/Index/1234

Essa rota sempre irá chamar o controller `RepresentanteController`

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Representante",
              url: "{representante}/{action}/{chave}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Representante", action = "Index", chave = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Porém se depois do nome do representante quiser chamar outro `Controller` que não seja o `RepresentanteController` não irá conseguir, pois a rota vai assumir que o primeiro parâmetro depois do nome do representante é a ação.

A rota acima não funciona com: http://localhost/jose/pedidos/listar pois irá achar que "pedidos" é uma ação do controller `RepresentanteController`

A seguinte forma fica melhor:

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Representante",
              url: "{representante}/{controller}/{action}/{chave}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Representante", action = "Index",  chave = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Ai funciona: http://localhost/jose/pedidos/listar ou http://localhost/jose/pedidos/detalhe/10

Mas também se quiser acessar o controller SobreController em http://localhost/Sobre não vai conseguir, pois será assumido que "sobre" é o nome do representante, enviando pro controller Representante, ai teria que criar rotas especificas como a abaixo, e essa rota abaixo deverá vir antes da rota do representante:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "Sobre",
                  url: "sobre",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Sobre", action = "Index" }
                );
```

Comment: Murilo, eu não conseguir entender como isso iria funcionária, fiz um teste é nada mudou

Comment: Vou corrigir algo que errei e vai dar certo. Fique de olho